# Adding Image and background to NatTable rows

Tags: java, nattable

I have read the documentation at: https://eclipse.org/nattable/documentation.php?page=styling

I am curious if there is any easy way to add background row colors and images using separate configurations.  I do not wish to combine them into 1 configuration like the CellPainterWrapper example because I want to separate the logic between the two.  My current code works for either the image or the background color, but I cannot do both (the top-most configuration overrides the bottom-most one).  Below is my snippet:

```
    void run(){
           addBackgroundRowColors();
           addImageToColumn();
    }

    void addImageToColumn() {
        getNatTable().addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                final Style cellStyleOne = new Style();
                cellStyleOne.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.IMAGE,
                   myIcon);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                   CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyleOne,
                   DisplayMode.NORMAL, myIconLabel);

                final Style cellStyleTwo = new Style();
                cellStyleTwo.setAttributeValue(CellStyleAttributes.IMAGE, 
                   myIcon2);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                   CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyleTwo,
                   DisplayMode.NORMAL, myIconLabel2);

                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                   CellConfigAttributes.CELL_PAINTER,
                   new CellPainterDecorator(new TextPainter(), 
                   CellEdgeEnum.LEFT, 10, new ImagePainter()),
                   DisplayMode.NORMAL);
            }
        });
        DataLayer dl = getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer();
        IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = (configLabels, 
          columnPosition, rowPosition) -> {
               // Label code here...
        };

        dl.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
    }

    void addBackgroundRowColors() {
        getNatTable().addConfiguration(new AbstractRegistryConfiguration() {
            @Override
            public void configureRegistry(IConfigRegistry configRegistry) {
                Style cellStyleOne = new Style();
                cellStyleOne.setAttributeValue(
                  CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, myColorOne);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                  CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyleOne,
                  DisplayMode.NORMAL, myColorLabel1);

                Style cellStyleTwo = new Style();
                cellStyleTwo.setAttributeValue(
                  CellStyleAttributes.BACKGROUND_COLOR, cellStyleTwo);
                configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(
                  CellConfigAttributes.CELL_STYLE, cellStyleTwo,
                  DisplayMode.NORMAL, myColorLabel2);
            }
        });
        DataLayer dl = getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer();
        IConfigLabelAccumulator cellLabelAccumulator = (configLabels, 
          columnPosition, rowPosition) -> {
               // Label code here...
        };

       dl.setConfigLabelAccumulator(cellLabelAccumulator);
    }
```

### Update

I ended up doing something similar to the following to make it work:

```
  AggregateConfigLabelAccumulator aggregate = 
    new AggregateConfigLabelAccumulator();
  aggregate.add(addImageToColumn());
  aggregate.add(addBackgroundRowColors());

  getGlazedListsGridLayer().getBodyDataLayer().
    setConfigLabelAccumulator(aggregate);
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you want to get rid of the single CellPainterWrapper in the configuration? I don't think that would work in a simple way. Or is the above snippet what you want to do? From a first look that should work. Do you add both labels to the label stack in your label accumulator?

Comment: My question is how do I make this work using the code snippet above?  I do not want to intermingle my code for images and background colors into one massive method. The above snippet is what I would like to do. Each IConfigLabelAccumulator adds its own labels to the stack. In other words, the background color label accumulator only deals with the background color labels. The image label accumulator only deals with image labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments the real question is about how to support separated `IConfigLabelAccumulator`. As you can only register one `IConfigLabelAccumulator` per layer, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. register the different `IConfigLabelAccumulator` on different layers
2. Use an `AggregateConfigLabelAccumulator` where you can combine multiple `IConfigLabelAccumulator`

This is also explained in the Getting Started Tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/NatTable/article.html

Comment: Awesome, the AggregateConfigLabelAccumulator worked great! I updated the original question so others can see the code snippet